# why does my code hang?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me, synchronized

I'm very curious about this thing. I have some code, in a synchronized block,
which calls an SDK method but it hangs.

```
synchronized(someObject) {
   someSDKobj.someMethd();
}
```

If I make the same call from an unsynchronized block it executes correctly.

```
//synchronized(someObject) 
{
   someSDKobj.someMethd();
}
```

One reason to hang is if the sdk method makes a call, on a different thread, to another method that synchronizes on the same 'someObject', but that's not the case.

What else can cause this strange phenomena? why would the called method be affected by the fact that it's been called from a synchronized block? If it matters, this is running on Java-ME.

Comment: please detail what method you are calling there is not enough information here at all, it could be deadlock or some other issue.

Comment: Did you see where exactly it hangs? Are you positive it's even entering the synchronized block? You are making the community wonder about all these things when you don't provide compilable code.

Comment: are you sure you need to synchronize on the same object you call the method on? what SDK method is it? what other code uses the object?

Comment: Maybe the locks on Java-ME are not reentrant, so thet a thread can deadlock itself?

Comment: @JakubZaverka locks on [Java ME](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-me/info) are reentrant. Given the terrible incompleteness of code snippet, one can safely guess that OP just syncs on `someObject` somewhere else in their own code - this could potentially lead to problem exactly like described

Answer (score 3):

It hangs because you created a condition called "deadlock". The problem is that a synchronized method can be accessed only by one thread at the time. So, your method is accessing this sync method, and calling another thread to access the same method, which is locked. So, the second thread is waiting for the function to be released by the other thread, and this never happens.

Comment: it could be a dead lock or it could be the process is merely hanging for another reason and never returning

Comment: You are explaining stuff the guy is obviously aware of.

Comment: Have a look at the dining philosophers problem for more detail around the concept of a deadlock.

Comment: i thought the "one reason" part was the case. The last sentence says "it's not the case". Unsure if i should delete this or leave it to be helpful to someone who knows nothing about deadlocks...

Comment: i am familiar with deadlocks and the dining philosophers... (thanks Marko). i stated why this can happen in he paragraph that starts with "One reason to hang..." (so you don't need to repeat it in your own words) - i ruled it out. that's why i find it strange. it's as if the sdk is affected by the fact that it's been called from a synchronized block. this only happens on a certain phone so it may be something weird about that impl'n, but i'm just curious how something like that can happen

Comment: Krystan, you say that the process may be hanging for another reason... if i make a call to some sdk method, assume nothing happens now other than that call. why would the called method hang only if it's called from within a synchronized block. one stupid reason i thought of is if there is some limit that has been reached, for example, too many synchronized blocks... obviously that's not the case, but perhpas something like that... sdk is reaching some limit and can't continue... ?

Answer (score 0):

Get a thread dump when it hangs.  This should tell you for sure what is going on in each thread of your JVM, including pointing up any lock contention.